# React typescript how to use useRef as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm just play around with typescript and 
I've got problem to use useRef in a custom element

passing it as prop

I've tried with

```
import React from "react";

export interface InputProps
  extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    ref: HTMLElement | null
  }

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ ...inputProps }) => {
  return (
    <input
      className="px-2 py-1 text-gray-700 text-2xl bg-white border-2 border-gray-200 hover:border-purple-300 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white rounded-l-lg shadow-md"
      {...inputProps}
    />
  );
};
export default Input;


import React, { useRef } from "react";

import Input from "./input";
import Button from "./button";

const Form: React.FC = () => {
  const todoRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  return (
    <form onSubmit={}>
      <Input type="text" id="todo" ref={todoRef}/>
      <Button type="submit">+</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

What's the right way, please?

### UPDATE

I worked out with:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-useref-example-e0hc4

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `React.forwardRef` on the component you are passing the ref to, like so:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLElement, InputProps>(({ ...inputProps }, ref) => {
  return (
    <input
      ref={ref}
      className="px-2 py-1 text-gray-700 text-2xl bg-white border-2 border-gray-200 hover:border-purple-300 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white rounded-l-lg shadow-md"
      {...inputProps}
    />
  );
});
```

Refs are treated differently than normal props. They are not included in the `props` object. To expose a ref inside a custom component you have to use `forwardRef`. Once the ref is exposed inside your component, you should assign it to one of the components in your return statement (usually the top level component, `input` in this case).

---

UPDATE:

If you're seeing the error `React.HTMLElement is not assignable to type React.HTMLInputElement` you should change the type of ref that you're creating to the appropriate one:

```
const todoRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)
```

and in the input component change the first line to:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(({ ...inputProps }, ref) => {
```

Comment: Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.

Comment: I've got (JSX attribute) React.ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.ref?: string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined
Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.

Comment: Type it as an input element `HTMLInputElement`.

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = React.forwardRef((inputProps, ref) => {  
return(  
    <input
      className="px-2 py-1 text-gray-700 text-2xl bg-white border-2 border-gray-200 hover:border-purple-300 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white rounded-l-lg shadow-md"
      ref={ref}      
      {...inputProps}
    />
)
})
export default Input;
```

output here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-useref-example-p3hh4

Comment: Yes, I do there is this error const Input: React.FunctionComponent<InputProps>
Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<InputProps, "accept" | "alt" | "autoComplete" | "autoFocus" | "capture" | "checked" | "crossOrigin" | "disabled" | "form" | "formAction" | "formEncType" | "formMethod" | ... 269 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & RefAttributes<...>>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<InputProps>'.
  Types of property 'defaultProps' are incompatible.
    Type 'Partial<Pick<InputProps, "accept" | "alt" | "autoComplete" | "autoFocus" | "capture" | "checked" |

Comment: This error in your code or my demo ? if in your code then need you make a simple codesandbox demo to review

Comment: It is in both :(

Comment: I can't see any error in demo, in my sample when click on button then focus move to input, just for test, and work as correctly

Comment: Put the mouse over row number 13 to see the error const Input: React.FC

Comment: That's not error just warning you can see in line 17 too

Answer (score -2):

Try one of this:

1. Use HTMLInputElement instead of HTMLElement
2. `<Input type="text" id="todo" ref={todoRef as any}/>`
3. Wrap the HTMLElement type into a ReactElement generic type